# How to prove that this coordinate system is ortoghonal?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a coordinate system $(u,v)$ given by:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
u&=&xy \\
v&=&\ln(y)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

How can i check if it is ortoghonal, find the unit vectors and find the Jacobian determinant for this C.S?.

**What i have done**, is search the definitions.

It will be OG if the inner product of his unit vectors is $0$:

$$<v_i,v_j>=0 \quad i \neq j$$

But i need the unit vectors, and those are:

$$e_i=\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial q_i}$$

For a point $P(q_1,q_2,...,q_n)$ where

$$\vec{r}=h_1 \textrm{d} q_1 \hat{q}_{1}+h_2\textrm{d} q_2 \hat{q}_{2}+h_3 \textrm{d}q_3 \hat{q}_{3}$$

But i dont know how to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to find line element in the new coordinate system. According to the definition:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y &=& e^v \\
x &=& u e^{-v}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

so one can write:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
dy &=& e^v dv \\
dx &=& - u e^{-v} dv + e^{-v} du
\end{eqnarray}
$$

so the line element is:
$$
\textrm{d}s^2 = \textrm{d}x ^2 + \textrm{d}y^2 = (u^2 e^{-2v}+ e^{2v}) \textrm{d}v^2 -2 u e^{-2v} \textrm{d}u \textrm{d}v + e^{-2u} \textrm{d}u^2  
$$

so this is not an orthogonal system otherwise coefficient of $\textrm{d}u \textrm{d}v$ was zero.

Comment: If it were OG, how can you get the unit vectors?

Comment: I strongly suggest reading chapter 2 of [Arfken&Weber](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vlFBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate partials and scalar product:
$$\begin{array}{l}
u = xy,v = \ln (y)\\
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _x}u}\\
{{\partial _y}u}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
y\\
x
\end{array}} \right),\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _x}v}\\
{{\partial _y}v}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
{\frac{1}{y}}
\end{array}} \right)\\
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _x}u}\\
{{\partial _y}u}
\end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _x}v}\\
{{\partial _y}v}
\end{array}} \right) = y \cdot 0 + x \cdot \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x}{y} \ne 0
\end{array}$$
Jacobian is regular:
$$\det \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _x}u}&{{\partial _x}v}\\
{{\partial _y}u}&{{\partial _y}v}
\end{array}} \right) = \det \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
y&0\\
x&{\frac{1}{y}}
\end{array}} \right) = 1$$

Comment: The unit vectors are the partial derivatives?

Comment: @VictorFranciscoSalazarGarci No. I checked if the tangent vectors are
orthogonal. But they aren't. So no need to normalize them. If they were
orthogonal, then one can divide them by their length to get unit vectors.
Here is no need to do so.